# want to call function "_popen" from vb6 program

Tags: vb6

I try to call "_popen" from vb6 (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/99456/EN-US), I was not successful, I tried:

```
Private Declare Function "_popen" Lib "msvcrt.dll" () As Long

Sub Main()
  Dim fnum As Integer
  fnum = _popen("netstat -ano", "r")
```

Thanks a lot in advance
Wolfgang

Comment: what do you mean by 'not successful'?

Answer (score 1):

You are going to need more than that anyway in order to get any practical use out of it.  In a VB6 program you are going to want to do async operations on the redirected StdIO streams.

One way to do this is to use a ShellPipe control, see [ShellPipe "Shell with I/O Redirection" control](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?660014-VB6-ShellPipe-quot-Shell-with-I-O-Redirection-quot-control).